# Setting SKSpriteNode position makes sprite dissapear

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift

After reading the documentation on how to position sprites using SpriteKit for the past few days I can't seem to make heads or tails of it. 
The image itself is 181 × 88. My

```
import SpriteKit

class PlayScene: SKScene {

let runningBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"runningbar")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex:0x80D9FF)
    self.runningBar.position = CGPointZero
    self.addChild(self.runningBar)
}...
```

My button does not show up at all. I would think that since the bottom left corner is 0,0 that I would see the top right corner of the button on the bottom left corner of the screen. The documentation say that it centers the texture on the button.

If I put another image on there that is 1344 × 64 then I see a little bit of the top right hand corner of the image in the bottom left hand corner. I am completely confused as to how the coordinate system works. What I read was that the anchor is in the center of the sprite.

Currently I have `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill`

Comment: check scene scalemode, change it to aspectFit or resizeFill

Comment: @LearnCocos2D it is set to `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill` for the scene.

Comment: Please show more of your code. You may be doing something later on that's affecting it's position.

Answer (score 0):

I am learning swift right now as well.  When accessing the variable runningBar you do not need to use "self." to access it.  Also I changed your position code so that it is based on a calculation of the current frame.  Right now it is set as direct center, but you should be able to figure out how to move it, just remember that CGPointMake needs to be : (x, y).

```
import SpriteKit

class PlayScene: SKScene {

let runningBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"runningbar")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex:0x80D9FF)

    runningBar.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.5, self.frame.size.height * 0.5)
    self.addChild(runningBar)
}
```